# Unable to set default value for swappiness

Tags: ram, swap

I have an Ubuntu 15.04 64bit with 4GB RAM.
I do not have a separate swap partition, but a swapfile of 8GB. The system recognizes the swap.

I have tried to set `swappiness` to 15 by adding it to the last line of `/etc/sysctl.conf`. The last 3 lines of `$cat /etc/sysctl.conf` are

```
# ADDED ON 9JAN16 for swap trial
vm.swappiness=15
#
```

However, when my system starts up, the swappiness value is 1

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
1
```

Manually setting `vm.swappiness` changes the value

```
$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=15
vm.swappiness = 15
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
15
```

Swappiness becomes 1 again when I boot up the system next time.

**NOTE** - I had previously tried to setup hibernation using [Debian's tutorial to hibernate without a swap partition](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition) and failed. I have removed `uswusp` that I had installed for that process. Perhaps there is something in there that is overriding `sysctl.conf`, but I am not smart enough to figure it out.

How do I set default value of swappiness to 15?

Comment: Is there more than one occurrence of `vm.swappiness` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file?

Comment: @JeffreyLam - there is just one occurence of `vm.swappiness`

Comment: I am out of ideas then. Is there another way of setting swappiness? I don't know of any myself, but I would wonder whether some setting elsewhere overrides the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file

Comment: @JeffreyLam - added a tale of my failed exploits. Please see if this sheds any more light

Comment: for a bit of extra background info: man pages are available for both sysctl and sysctl.conf and can be accessed from the terminal with `man sysctl` and `man sysctl.conf`. They are also available in various places online: such as http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html for sysctl and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html for sysctl.conf.

Comment: Actually the above link is different from [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl), which says _Please note that modules loaded after sysctl is run may override the settings (example: sunrpc.* settings are overridden when the sunrpc module is loaded). This may cause some confusion during boot when the settings in sysctl.conf may be overriden. To prevent such a situation, sysctl must be run after the particular module is loaded._ Do you know if you might have modules loading that might override this setting? You might have to look in your `modprobe.conf` file(s)

Comment: I found something in your [Debian tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition). _Create a file called local.conf in /etc/sysctl.d and add the kernel variable there so it sticks:_ `vm.swappiness=1`. Is this /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf file still there? Does it still say `vm.swappiness=1` inside it?

Comment: @JeffreyLam - there was no `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf` file. I must have deleted it when reversing the steps I did for enabling hibernation

Comment: argh! I thought we had it. Can you post these into your question: your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and the contents of your `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory? (The commands `cat /etc/sysctl.conf` and `ls -l /etc/sysctl.d/` will get these) There might be something in one of the files inside the sysctl.d directory that sets the swappiness.

Comment: Actually. it turns out that there was some `.conf` file in `etc/sysctl.d/` that had a line to set swappiness. Deleted that and swappiness is now set via `/etc/sysctl.conf`.



Thanks for all the help

Comment: Good job! Glad that is fixed. Would you be kind enough to up-vote one or two of my comments that you found helpful? I could do with the reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a `.conf` in `/etc/sysctl.d/` that had the line setting `vm.swappiness = 1`

Deleting that allows swappiness to be set from `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

I guess the takeaway from this issue is that a `.conf` file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` can override an entry in `/etc/sysctl.conf`